# Where to put amazon.sdktester.json file in Android?

Tags: android, json, amazon-web-services

To test Amazon In-app purchase, we are required to put amazon.sdktester.json file in the location **/mnt/sdcard/**, but I am not able to find this location in Android 4.2. My question is, am I doing something wrong to find the location and if not What could be the alternative for this? Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my device the location for amazon.sdktester.json file to work properly is /storage/emulated/0. So, we can place our file in this location for Android 4.2 to function properly with Amazon SDKTester.

You can also achieve this by dragging and dropping your file to /mnt/sdcard/ location visible for your device in file explorer in DDMS. This is how I came to know the above written fact.
Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think android version has anything to do with it, so you might rename question so more people click it.

Anyway
sdcard folder suggests that you have sd card in your device, at least I see it like that. I also did not have a folder like that so what worked for me was to put the json in the root folder. 
Example: *(Computer -> device -> *put json here*)*.

Creating /mnt/sdcard directory did **not** work.

Comment: You are right about Android version having nothing to do with this. At that time I didn't think it that way. Anyway thanks for point out.